# Java: Unreachable statement for switch using modulus operator

Tags: java

I am attempting to work through a hackerrank algorithm challenge which will predict the height of a tree after a series of alternating weather patterns. I'm not sure why my logic isn't working. Java says that the break points in my `switch` statement are not working. I have pasted the code below in full.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt(); // user input how many test cases
    System.out.println("test cases set.");
    int[] cycles = new int[i];

    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        cycles[x] = scan.nextInt(); // user input test cycles
    }


    for (int x = 0; x < i; x++) {
        System.out.println(cycles[x]);
        int temp = predictor(cycles[x]);
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}


public static int predictor(int cycles) {
    // determines the remainder to find even or odd cycle year
    int heightRemainder = cycles % 2;

    switch (heightRemainder) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Even number");
            return cycles; // UNREACHABLE, cycles is a temp variable to check functionality
            break;


        case 1:
            System.out.println("Odd number");
            return cycles; // UNREACHABLE, same here
            break;
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Each of your break statements is immediately preceded by a return statement. There is no way for the break statements to be executed.

Comment: after program execute  *return statement*  then it end, so the code after *return statement* make no sense

Comment: So when a return statement is used in a `switch` there is generally no need to use a `break`? @PatriciaShanahan Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: @Pahjay All you need is some transfer of control that will prevent fall-through to the next case. There are arguments against having multiple return statements, and you don't seem to need more than one here.

Comment: @Pahjay - It is not as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will not work because your break statement is after return statement, execution control will not go to break statement.

Instead of returning in switch case use variable to store value of cycles and then return that variable at end of method, like this

```
public static int predictor(int cycles) {
// determines the remainder to find even or odd cycle year
int heightRemainder = cycles % 2;
 int r=-1;


switch (heightRemainder) {
    case 0:
        System.out.println("Even number");
        r =cycles; 
        break;


    case 1:
        System.out.println("Odd number");
         r=cycles
        break;
     }
    return r;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

in the predictor method: remove the break; statement...  that is dead code because you are returning the cycle values

```
switch (heightRemainder) {
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Even number");
            return cycles; // UNREACHABLE, cycles is a temp variable to check functionality
          case 1:
            System.out.println("Odd number");
            return cycles; // UNREACHABLE, same here
  }
```